# REST API for registration

Tags: java, rest, captcha, recaptcha

We want to implement a public RESTful API integrated in our software (written in java) that might be used by various clients to build small e-commerce apps (e.g. for Android or iPhone). This API includes getting a list of products, categories, shopping cart support, etc.

We need to provide an API that will allow user registration and couple of other sensitive functions. How should we protect this API against spam and bruteforcing? In the standard product we use `reCAPTCHA`. Any alternative for the REST counterpart?

Answer (score 1):

First, think of separation of concerns. What is the purpose of REST API?

A REST API should do offer a service to the client. Client sends a request via REST protocol, and gets a response for its request. In code, this looks something like:

```
@GET
public Response getClientInfo(@QueryParam("clientId") Integer clientId) {
     ClientDTO clientDTO = database.getClientInfo(clientId);
     return ResponseWrapper.wrap(clientDTO);
}
```

Now, you want your REST method doing ONLY this and nothing else. Otherwise, you would put **block-bruteforce-and-spam-logic** in your REST method and you would get a mess of the code that is not extensible, hard to version, etc. If you want to change your, e.g. blacklisting policy you would have to change each and every REST method, and it's bulky. If you want to check the calls before the make it to REST methods, then take a look at Filters. Every request and response pass through a chain of filters and could be check for misuse of the server.

I don't know what is your technology stack is, but I would suggest looking into these:

- JBoss AS7.
- [DeltaSpike](https://cwiki.apache.org/DeltaSpike/temporary-documentation.html#TemporaryDocumentation-SecurityModule) (enables you powerful Interceptors that will check user rights and execution rights before the execution of the REST method).

for example:

```
@LoggedInUser
@GET
public Response getClientInfo(...) {
    ...
}
```

This security annotation `@LoggedInUser` (which, by the way, you define) will give sign to an Interceptor to check this security constraint, e.g.

```
@Secures (built in annotation)
@LoggedInUser
public boolean hasRight(Identity identity) {
    return identity.isLoggedIn(); //or if he is in certain group of users
}
```

- Context and Dependency Injection context (used in DeltaSpike).
- JBoss Filters (a filter chain where you can create your own filter that, for example, checks if some IP is trying to send multiple calls within a very short period ~ 10 lines of code).

An example of the Filter

```
@Startup
@ApplicationScoped
@Filter(around= "org.jboss.seam.web.ajax4jsfFilter")
public class IPTrackerFilter extends AbstractFilter {

    //IPTracker is your @ApplicationScoped bean that remembers all IP addresses accessing the application.
    @Inject
    private IPTracker fIPTracker;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (!(req instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        final String ipAddress= ((HttpServletRequest)req).getRemoteAddr();
        if (fIPTracker.isBlackListed(ipAddress)) {
            //implement error message here
            sendErrorMessage(response);
            return;
        } else {
            //all good, continue
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
}
```

PS. I gave you  the link for [DeltaSpike](https://cwiki.apache.org/DeltaSpike/temporary-documentation.html#TemporaryDocumentation-SecurityModule), for others is really easy to find. Also, if you find DeltaSpike to obscure, try with [JBoss Seam Security Framework](http://www.seamframework.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The technology that we are using is a small framework built a top of Jersey. We have secured the calls available for logged in users, unfortunately there are some calls that are permitted for anonymous users (e.g. registration). These should be somehow secured against spammers, bots, abusive users, etc. I'll read through the links that you provided.

Comment: Then take a look at `ContainerRequestFilter`.